# Password mismatch between the command line and the graphical environment (after error while messing with ansible)

Tags: command-line, password, gui

all,

I am on an Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Recently, I have been playing with ansible, and not knowing exactly what was happening, I modified my own system instead of the system I was configuring in the cloud.

The problem I am experiencing since then, is that my password when logging in on the GUI is still OK, but whenever I try to do something where I need administrative priviliges *when working in the graphical environment*, I can't do it any longer, but I *CAN* do it on the command line : `sudo su -` still works as normal there. I would like to re-enable my rights *when working in the user interface*, to perform actions with administrative privileges (like e.g. modifying netword adapter settings).

There must be some internal incosistency, but I can't find out what it would be. I noticed that not any user on my (home computer) system is any longer part of the administrators, according to the user interface. But this is definitely not true, as `sudo su -` still works fine on the command line.

So where could this inconsistency be ? I am totally puzzled, and help would be very welcome...

Comment: Do you get a password prompt in the GUI and then it doesn't accept your password or do you not get a pop-up at all? My first thought would be that you messed up the `askpass` setting in `/etc/sudo.conf`.

Comment: 1. at startup, I am prompted to click the user to login (there are 3 users on this computer, I am the first one ever having been setup).
2. Then, I click my user account and enter my password (which succeeds)
3. Next, still in the GUI, I can do all actions I want APART FROM those actions where I need administrator rights for.
4. When I want to perform some action for which I need administrator rights, I am prompted for the password. Entering the exact same password as when I login ... FAILS...

Comment: (I realise I don't have any sudo.conf file in /etc however)

Comment: @Wayne Vosberg After being triggered by your input, I started looking up some things, tried some things, and now it works. The only thing I can think which has solved it, could have been that I (re?)installed ssh-askpass-gnome, OR that I executed `usermod -aG sudo <my-username>`.

Thank you for your input !

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't know if I can, as I am pretty new here (I don't know if I have enough credits already). Moreover, I'm not sure about exactly what caused my environment to restart working properly, as I did a couple of things and I can't be sure about what caused it to start working again ...

Comment: It's up to you but yes, you can answer your own questions or others regardless of reputation. You need 50+ to comment but asking and answering doesn't depend on rep.